# How to show multiple selected items in an ListBox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have a ListBox where you can select multiple items and these save to a database. That all works fine but when I go back into the ListBox to view the items only the first one is selected, even though I had selected 3.

ListBox:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" ID="txtEdtContactDocuments"></asp:ListBox>
```

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>').length; i++) {
  for (var x=0;x<result.Docs.length;x++) {
        if (Number(document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>')[i].value) == Number(result.Docs[x].DocType)) {
              document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>')[i].selected = "selected";
              } else {
                 document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>')[i].selected = "";
                 document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>')[i].selected = false;
              }
        }
  }
```

The loops are looking correctly, it does find the 3 items I selected but they are not getting highlighted in the list:

[image]

I also tried `document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>')[i].selected = true;` but that change anything. Only the first item still got selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an algorithmical issue. Assuming that there are more than one items in the `result.Docs` collection, you are overwriting what you might have set in earlier iterations of the `for (var x=0;x<result.Docs.length;x++)` loop.

Your algorithm should work if you put `break;` statement after this line: `document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>')[i].selected = "selected";`. It will terminate the inner loop when the appropriate item is found.

However, I'd recommend refactoring the code and getting rid of the inner loop completely. You can replace it with a LINQ query, for instance.

Note: there's no need to use jQuery or any other JS framework. You can easily do achieve the task with vanilla JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/hjybjz3e/

Answer (score -1):

Try using jQuery to set the selected options.

Replace

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>')[i].selected = "selected";
```

With:

```
$('#<%= txtEdtContactDocuments.ClientID %>').eq(i).attr("selected", "true");
```

.eq() is a jQuery function to select the object at a specific index much the same us using [] notation.